# Eating treif under hashgacha

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, sin

What happens if someone eats at a restaurant with a kosher certification (hashgacha) but is served, and unknowingly eat non-kosher? What are the spiritual and halachic ramifications to all parties involved including: the patron, the cook, the mashgiach, the waiter, (assuming he's Jewish) restaurant owner?  Who has commited a sin? Who would need to bring a korban and to teshuva?

Comment: What does it mean to get a sin, and which sin are you referring to?

Comment: @DoubleAA the sin of eating non-kosher

Comment: You want to know if they are held accountable in Heaven for sinning without knowing it?

Comment: @nikmasi How could someone who didn't eat not-kosher 'get' the sin of eating not kosher?

Comment: I'll write this as a comment, since I'm unfamiliar with the halakha, but the masekhta that you want to look at is Horayot, which deals with precisely this issue (erroneous rulings that lead to communal transgressions, and who foots the blame). Within the context of that masekhta, "getting the sin" refers to liability for a chatat - which I'm guessing is what you are referring to here?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's a *chakira* in the nature of *lifnei iver*; one approach is that it is as if someone who violates *lifnei iver* violated the specific *issur* in question. A *nafka minah* would be if a person who leads someone else to violate Shabbos could be considered a *mumar l'chol haTorah* or just a *mumar l'davar echad*.

Comment: @DoubleAA are you taking issue with the phrasing? The question is clearly "who has sinned?" or "who is Halachically responsible?"

Comment: @Fred :) Indeed it is! I wondered if anyone would bring that up.

Comment: @yoel What does it mean to be Halachically responsible in this case? I understand the question "Am I allowed to do X" and "If I did X must I do Y", but this doesn't seem to be either of those.

Comment: @DoubleAA How about "when X occurred, who committed an aveira?"

Comment: @yoel "aveira" like עובר על דעת המלך like didn't do what s/he was supposed to do? I can accept that because it's essentially asking what action should (have) be(en) taken in a certain circumstance. Otherwise I'm not sure what you are asking, unless it's "who gets a lump of coal added to their heavenly scale?" which I don't think anyone here is really qualified to answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think he's asking how much the coal weighs.  Do you really not believe that Jewish law can qualify whether or not a particular action or inaction is an aveira?

Comment: @yoel I think it can qualify what anyone should do in a given situation. It might say 'do not steal' and it will also say 'if you did steal, pay X' and it might say 'if you do X bring a korban' or 'if you do X you must do teshuva == charata, pirut, kabbalah". But in general, yes, Halacha is a system that tells you what to do (הלכ=to go). I do not think Halacha defines things that are useless to us.

Comment: It might help to separate the spiritual and legal aspects of the question. Both draw on the question of whether such a person is guilty of an unintentional sin. If so, legally, what do they need to do if it's found out? But spiritually there's the question of whether unintentional sins affect a person's spiritual wellbeing, or holiness in the context of the Temple and relationship with God, regardless of whether they're discovered. A separate question would consider the 'spiritual ramifications' of non-kosher food, regardless of whether a person is held responsible for accidentally taking it.

Comment: Though I wouldn't suggest that those questions all can be answered with more than speculation. They're important in a sense of understanding, and maybe that understanding is important in the halachic process. But on another level they're not so practical.